# Sliding from Down to Up

Tags: jquery

I got a `<div>` which I would like to slide from Down to Up instead of Up to Down.

When I tried:`$('#div_slide').slideDown(1000);` the `<div>` didn't even show. when I do:

```
$('#div_slide').slideUp(1000);
```

it does work, but slides from the very top to the very bottom, and I want it to be the opposite, to open itself from DOWN to UP, from the Bottom to the Top.

How do I do that?

Comment: What browser/environment is this on? Can you give us the relevant HTML/CSS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS

```
 .block {
    position: relative;
    width: 320px;
    height: 260px;
    display: block;
    background: pink;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.slidemeup{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    display: none;
    width: 260px;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

HTML

```
    <div class="block">
    <div class="slidemeup">
    this will slidedown in revwrse direction</div>
    </div>
```

JS

```
jQuery(".block").hover(
    function(){
        jQuery(".slidemeup").slideDown();
    },
    function(){
    jQuery(".slidemeup").slideUp('fast');
});
```

Check out this working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eGA6B/) here

Comment: I tried this: ` $('#computers_feedback').show("slide",{direction: "up"},1000);` but it didn't work

Comment: well, this solution works **only** for a div which has the bottom attribute. if I'm using margin-top to set the div down to the page, this solution won't work :(